# Java Client status monitoring

Tags: java, client-server, monitoring, messaging

I have java based server application and multiple java clients. Based upon some activity at the client side, client send some messages to the server.
The requirement is to monitor the state of the client.

**What is the best possible/efficient design to address this requirement?**
There could be more than 10,000 clients. Should we follow heartbeat mechanism or some other technique?

Should we persist the status of each client in db for reporting purpose?

Comment: What type of server do you have? Is it using pure Sockets, RMI, SOAP, REST, ... ?

Comment: It is java application deployed on tomcat server and using REST. Even client is using REST to send messages to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you write something like this yourself when there are a number of off-the-shelf options. Have a look at new relic, it does client server monitoring like you just described and a whole lot more.